# Why does the formal procedure prove NP-Completeness?

Tags: algorithm, proof, np-complete

I know how to show that a problem X is NP-Complete.

1. Show that X ∈ NP.
2. Show Y ≤*p* X: show a problem Y known to be NP-Complete can be reduced to X in polynomial time.

However, I'm stuck on *why* this procedure proves that X is NP-Complete. Could someone explain this  in a relatively simple way?

Comment: [Computer Science](http://cs.stackexchange.com/) would be a better fit for this question.

Comment: You're probably right; sorry about that. Should I delete the question and re-ask there?

Comment: For a given NP-complete problem Y, we already know that any other problem in NP can be reduced to it in polynomial time. If you now who that Y <=p X (which is the direction you need), then you know by transitivity of polynomial reductions (polynomial times polynomial = polynomial) that any problem in NP can now be reduced to X.

Comment: That's just *how it's defined*.  At the end of the day, it's just a man-made category.

Comment: @G.Bach you're right. I updated the question accordingly. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NP Complete problem is defined to be a problem that is both NP-Hard and in NP (definition), so you basically need to show 2 things:

1. The problem is in NP (same as your 1)
2. The problem is NP-Hard

You can show (2) by 2 ways:

1. Prove directly that there is a reduction from every problem in NP to it (hard to do)
2. Show a reduction from any known NP-Hard problem to your problem.

The thing is, reduction is [transitive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_relation), so if you prove there is a reduction from some NP-Hard problem (let it be `L1`) to your problem (Let it be `L2`), you basically showed that there is a reduction from EVERY `L` in NP to `L1` (definition of NP-Hard), and from `L1` to `L2` (your reduction), thus the chain of these reductions (which is itself polynomial, neat things about polynoms), is a reduction by itself from every `L` in NP to `L2` (your problem).

In other words, since `L <=p L1 <=p L2` for every `L`, it follows that `L <=p L2` for every `L` as well, and this is the exact definition of NP-Hardness.

This way, you showed there is a reduction from every problem in NP to your problem, and this is the definition of NP-Hardness.

---

Since showing directly that there is a reduction from EVERY `L` in NP to a language, it was done once on [SAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem) ([Cook-Levin theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cook%E2%80%93Levin_theorem)) [twice actually...], and now you can use reductions to increase the number of known NP-Hard Problems.

Comment: 2 is in the wrong direction. You want to reduce an NP-hard problem to your problem, not the other way around. Also, reductions are not transitive in general; polynomial reductions are, however.

Comment: @G.Bach thanks, note that the explanation however follows the "correct" direction.

Comment: @amit Could you take a look at my question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29706726/reduction-to-clique-prob